# Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat' [No stack trace available] in R shiny webtool

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

Im developing shiny webtool for R functions to generate the indices results on the webtool.

I have 6 R functions and i created 6 combinations in selectinput widget, where each combination is linked with the one R function each.

The 6 R functions are as follows:

RSCU(file){script},

cgr_res(file){script},

zscore_cal(file){script},

GC_Content7(file){} and

extractmod(file){script} all these 5 functions have single and same arguments i.e., input file as same input argument for all five R functions
and last R function that is **6th R function have AMIP(file,n1,n2)** 3 input arguments here input file is same as remaining 5, but n1 and n2 are different arguments ,
for n1 and n2 arguments I created numericalInput() widget.  For GC_content7,RSCU, cgr_res and zscore_cal, webtool is working fine but for other two functions no results are displaying.

```
     library("shinythemes")
  library("shiny")
  library("htmltools")
  library("bsplus")
  library("DT")
  library("shinyalert")
  library("shinyjs")
  library("shinycssloaders")
  library("dplyr")
  library("data.table")
  library("reshape2")
  library("ggplot2")
  library("plotly")
  library("tools")
  library("readxl")
  library("writexl")
  library("seqinr")
  library("Biostrings")
  library("BiocManager")
  library("entropy")
  library("protr")
  
  source("GS_Source.R")
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    headerPanel(
      h1(tags$strong("Welcome to Web based Tool for Computation of Genomic"),
         style = "font-size: 20pt; line-height: 30pt; width = 100; color: #Red",
         align = "center"),
      windowTitle = "Home"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        style = "background-color: #E52B50;",
        tags$style(type='text/css', 
                   "label { font-size: 12px; }",
                   ".selectize-input { font-size: 12pt; line-height: 12pt;}, 
                   .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 12pt; line-height: 12pt; }"),
        
        fileInput('file', HTML('<p style="color:#4A2768; font-size: 12pt"> Choose file to upload the expression data </p>'),accept = c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values',
                                                                                                                                       'text/tab-separated-values','text/plain','.csv', '.tsv','.fasta')),
        
        selectInput("Signatures", HTML('<p style="color:#4A27C5; font-size: 12pt"> Genome signature </p>'), 
                    c("GC-content","RSCU","CGR","DI-nuculeotide odd Ratio","AAC","AMIP")),
        numericInput("num1",label = "FROM",value = 2),
        numericInput("num2", label = "TO", value = 3),
      
        useShinyalert(),
        actionButton("action", tags$b("Submit")), width = 3,  style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
      mainPanel(
       verbatimTextOutput("res1"),
        verbatimTextOutput("res2"),
       plotOutput("res3"),
       verbatimTextOutput("res4"),
       verbatimTextOutput("res5"),
       verbatimTextOutput("res6"),
        
      )
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
   
    
  
  df <- eventReactive(input$action, {
                      my_func <- switch(input$Signatures,
                                       
                                       "RSCU" = RSCU,
                                       "CGR"=cgr_res,
                                       "DI-nuculeotide odd Ratio"=zscore_cal,
                                       "GC-content" = GC_content7,
                                       "AAC"=extractAAC_mod,
                      )
                     
                      my_func(input$file$datapath)
                     
  })
  
  df1 <- eventReactive(input$actions, { 
                   my_func1 <- switch(input$signatures, 
                          "AMIP"=AMIP,
  )
     my_func1(input$file$datapath,input$num1,input$num2)
  })
  
  

  
  output$res1 <- renderPrint({
    req(input$Signatures)
    if (input$Signatures=="GC-content") {
      
      df()
    }
  })
  
  output$res2 <- renderPrint({
    req(input$Signatures)
    if (input$Signatures=="RSCU") {
      
      df()
    }
  })
    
  output$res3 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$Signatures)
    if (input$Signatures=="CGR") {
      
      df()
    }
  })
  
  output$res4 <- renderPrint({
    req(input$Signatures)
    if (input$Signatures=="DI-nuculeotide odd Ratio") {
      
      df()
    }
  })                    
  output$res5 <- renderPrint({
    req(input$Signatures)
    if (input$Signatures=="AAC") {
      
      df()
    }
  })
  
  output$res6 <- renderPrint({
   req(input$signatures)
    if(input$signatures=="AMIP"){
      df1()
      }
    
 })
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    shinyalert(title = "Please wait for the results...", type = "success")
  })
  
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hA2xyTUBG3Q7tr1JzUvJF5QFxQ7Ivo3s/view?usp=sharing                  link for sample dataset

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One cannot return a list in `renderText`. You can use `renderPrint` instead of `renderText` and `verbatimTextOutput` instead of `textOutput`.

Comment: thank you so much, I have another query can I ask u sir ?